# copying c code from replit to visual studio on mac

Tags: c, visual-studio, replit

So I went to copy my c code from replit to visual studio because I have to work on an assignment online.

I have a floating.h file I created for functions like toDouble(unsigned int) etc. when I include the file in my main.c and call the code, output says “_toDouble” are undefined symbols for architecture x86_64.

My actual implementation of the functions are in my floating.c file.

My floating.h has for example

“double toDouble(struct floating f)”

Comment: Did you link with floating.c ?

Comment: I I just did thank you so much! I did everything but that :D